# Weird Layout Behaviour in Magento Layout local.xml

Tags: xml, magento, templates, layout, php

Got a weird one that I'm a bit confused about, as I'm pretty sure I'm doing everything correctly here.

I'm using Magento CE 1.8.1.0 and this is my local.xml at the moment:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <!-- Blocks to Remove from Layout -->
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo" />
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout" />
        <reference name="right">
            <remove name="right.poll" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/combined.css</name></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>modernizr/modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="page/html_head" name="footer_scripts" as="footerScripts" after="-" template="page/html/footer/footer-scripts.phtml">
                <action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js</script></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/combined.js</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

The problem I'm having is the root template is not being set correctly. It's using the base 2columns-right.phtml file. What am I missing here?

Comment: on which page you want to set 2columns-left.phtml? so you have to set template on appropriate handle

Comment: I want to set it as the default root template. This has been sorted, as I forgot to go in to the CMS pages section and set the template.

Answer (score 0):

Can't dive into the code right now, but my guess is that because you use the default handle, it's overwritten by other layout handles

Answer (score 0):

For those of you scratching your head over this one when you've checked everything else.

As the home page is essentially a CMS page, it has a default template assigned to it under 'CMS > Pages > Home page > Design > Layout', so no matter how you override this in your layout XML files (local.xml) it will always use the one configured in the CMS. Simply change it to the one you want and it will use your custom .phtml file, as specified in your local.xml.